# Assistance in understanding LogUsage in VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi there Please may you help me interpret the following code.
SubjectID and Modality_Type are fields on a Microsoft Access form.

```
Private Sub Modality_Type_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not IsNull(Me.SubjectID) Then
        Call LogUsage(Me.Name, Modality_Type, Me.SubjectID)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It logs, I guess, an update of `Modality_Type` by recording the form's name, the modality type, and a subject id, probably as a new record in a table.